# Rails placeholder when building array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to do this:

```
query << ["AND f.name LIKE '%:last_name%' ", :last_name => params[:last_name] ]
```

But getting an error. Surely the syntax is incorrect.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: are you using rails 3?

Comment: "an error"? what error?

Comment: @Dogbert - syntax error, unexpected tASSOC, expecting ']'
...%:last_name%' ", :last_name => params[:last_name] ]

Comment: What is the error? what is query?

Answer (score 1):

Is this an array or an hash? the first item looks like an array and the second like a hash. Without some context it is hard to tell. You can start by maybe trying this:

```
["AND f.name LIKE '%:last_name%' ", {:last_name => params[:last_name]} ]
```

Comment: That gives me:  AND f.name LIKE '%:last_name%' last_name' some_last_name

Comment: So provide more details. what is query? why are you appending this array to it?

Comment: query is: query = []. Then I add string to it. At the end I use JOIN. And I want to use placeholder to avoid sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Where query is an array you may want to pass a string so you don't end up with an array of arrays, you could do this:

Rails 3

```
query << "AND f.name LIKE '%#{params[:last_name]}%' "
```

Rails 2

```
last_name = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(params[:last_name])
query << "AND f.name LIKE '%#{last_name}%' "
```

Comment: This is were I started. But it lets in SQL Injection.

Comment: If you're using rails 3 it will sanitize user input by default.  if not you could just pass the params through ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(params[:last_name])

Comment: you're still get the syntax error?  I was missing a space before the end quote, just incase you copy/pasted what i posted.

Answer (score 0):

since you're not using rails 3, you should use `scoped` to chain queries

```
records = Record.scoped(:conditions => { :active => true })
records = records.scoped(:conditions => ["records.name LIKE '%:last_name%' ", { :last_name => params[:last_name] }])
```

so you don't have to build queries like that.

Comment: But I want to build the query piece by piece, since it is a long one, and the JOIN all the pieces together.